# GTK popup menu not appearing at mouse position

Tags: python, menu, gtk

I'm trying to create a Gtk popup menu on button click using a handler as seen below:

```
def code_clicked(self,widget,event):
    newmenu=Gtk.Menu()
    newitem=Gtk.MenuItem('hello')
    newmenu.append(newitem)
    newitem1=Gtk.MenuItem('goodbye')
    newmenu.append(newitem1)
    newmenu.show_all()
    newmenu.popup(None,None,None,None,event.button,event.time)
    return True
```

The menu never appears. Theoretically, the third argument in popup, func, sets the position to the cursor position if set to Null. I think the problem is there since if I set func  to `lambda x,y: (event.x,event.y,True)`, it shows the popup menu some 100 pixels above my cursor.

I'd like to find some way to popup this menu at my cursor. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the root position of the window.
So

```
        menu.popup(None, None, 
                   lambda menu, data: (event.get_root_coords()[0],
                                       event.get_root_coords()[1], True),
                   None, event.button, event.time)
```

should put the popup at correct position. Works here.

As to answer of Jon Black, in GTK3, the question is correct, see http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.4/GtkMenu.html#gtk-menu-popup The deprecate pygtk bindings only work like you describe

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `event.time` as the data parameter, which is in turn passed to *func* to determine the menu position. Changing your call to the following should fix it:

```
newmenu.popup(None, None, None, event.button, event.time)
```

Comment: I apologize, I should clarify that I'm using Gtk in PyGObject, not PyGtk. The methods have slightly different signatures in the two of them. The signature I'm using is (I think) :

popup(parent_menu_shell, parent_ menu_item, func, data, button, activate_time)

Running your fix tells me that I haven't passed enough arguments (6 given, 7 required). Thanks for responding though!